# Laravel checking input isset

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Input helper has

> Input::has('debug')

My problem is that I often use query parameter without the value such has http://example.com?debug

The problem is that Input::has('debug') will return false in this case because there is no value.  ie. debug=1

So I end up having to use `isset($_GET['debug'])`.

Is there a laravel way to check whether the input isset?

Comment: As far as I know there is not. You will have to use `isset`. You cant change it to `debug=1`?

Comment: @Marwelln  yeah.. that's what I end up doing. debug=anything will work for has()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, use [`exists`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L186) method:

```
// http://example.com?debug
var_dump(app('request')->exists('debug')); // return true

// http://example.com
var_dump(app('request')->exists('debug')); // return false
```

Comment: Thanks.  It must be a newer function

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I did not know this function too