# When printing object variable, value is returned. When checking isset(), returning FALSE

Tags: php, laravel

Seems pretty straightforward. I am using a simple class called MaterialCategoryType, populating the variables, etc.

```
$materialCategoryType = new MaterialCategoryType;

$materialCategoryType->populate( $type );
```

This is working, and I can verify that by accessing any variable, including the one I am doing isset() on.

```
print $materialCategoryType->WebMaterialCategoryTypeId;
```

prints 'DE796581-6F27-4A97-GUID-B043GUIDF27C' (EXAMPLE)

And now the strange part. No redirects, no passing variables, etc. Same page, LITERALLY the NEXT lines are

```
if ( isset( $materialCategoryType->WebMaterialCategoryTypeId ) ){
    print "yep";
}else{
    print "nope";
}
```

Keeps printing "nope".

I am using Laravel, but this is the first time I have ever run into something strange like this.

Comment: Is **MaterialCategoryType** model? what is `->populate()` and `$type`

Comment: Maybe you want [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Comment: You may wish to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550009/laravel-checking-input-isset

Comment: personally I consider it bad practice to refer directly to properties in a class, it defeats the "black box" idea and separation of concerns.  But what do I know.

Comment: Can you post `MaterialCategoryType` class, with `__construct` and `populate` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`isset` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> **Warning**: isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

It is kind of hard to understand, but a **variable** attribute of an object **is not** a variable.

Comment: Using literally the exact same logic in multiple other places (on the same page) and it is working well.. Just this one spot. I am definitely interested as to why. Thank you for the resource, I will review it.

Comment: no, that just means that you should not use it like this `isset( anotherFunction() )` as it will throw parse error...

Comment: from [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php): **Note: As opposed with `isset()`, `property_exists()` returns TRUE even if the property has the value NULL.**

Comment: There are many cases where it would be tricky. For instance, if the property is private, but has a public get method (most common case in Laravel, I would say) isset would return different values depending on the php versión.